# How can I remove the right-margin on my nav bar?

Tags: html, css

I'm relatively new to HTML and CSS. I'm working on a portfolio website for class and am not using Bootstrap.

I can't seem to get rid of this small weird space on the right side of my page. I want my navbar to span the entire length of my page! The same thing is happening with my header image even when I change the margins, padding, etc. I'm out of ideas!

Any help/ideas would be appreciated. Thank you so much!

[example of the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ubK4s.jpg)

```css
/*                  GENERAL                    */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@400;700&family=Patrick+Hand&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    background-color:#ddd;
    background-size: cover;
    font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px;
}

h1 {
    background-color: rgba(229, 152, 155, .7);
    font-family: 'Patrick Hand', cursive;
    font-size: 80px;
    margin: -5px;
    text-align: center;
}

h2 {
    font-family: 'Patrick Hand', cursive;
}

h3 {
    font-family: 'Manrope', sans-serif;
    text-align: center;
}


/*                  NAV/LINKS                    */

nav {
    background-color: white;
    height: 70px;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-left:-5px;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}

nav h2 {
    color: black;
    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 55px;
    padding: 0px 20px;
}

nav ul {
    float:right;
    padding: 3px 20px 20px 3px;
}

nav ul li {
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    position: relative;
}

nav ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #AC6BA7;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 22px 14px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

nav ul li ul {
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 4px 4px;
    display: none;
    padding: 3px;
    position: absolute;
}

nav ul li:hover ul {
    display: block;
}

nav ul li ul li {
    border-radius: 4px;
}

nav ul li ul li a {
    padding: 8px 12px;
}

nav ul li ul li a:hover {
    background-color: #E5989B;
}

/*                  PAGE IMAGES                    */

.header-img {
    margin: -5px;
    width: 100%;
}


/*                  PAGES                    */



/*                  MEDIA QUERIES                    */



/*                  FOOTER                    */
```

```html
<!------ SKELETON CODE (SAME ON ALL PAGES) ------>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
    <title>Jen Nino: Class Website</title>
</head>

<body>
<!------ NAV BAR (SAME ON ALL PAGES) ------>

<nav>
    <h2>JEN NINO</h2>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">NAV ≡</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="webdesign.html">WORK</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<!------ HEADER (SAME ON ALL PAGES, DIFF IMAGE) ------>

<header>
    <img class="header-img" src ="images/sanfrancisco.png" alt="My husband and I in front of San Francisco Bay. There is a skyline in the background.">
</header>

<!------ MAIN/ARTICLE/SECTION (DIFFERENT ON PAGES) ------>

<main>
    <h1>HOME</h1>
    <article class="about-me-parent">

        <section class="about-me-child">
            <p> Text</p>
        </section>

        <section class="about-me-child">
            <p>Text </p>
        </section>
        
    </article>

</main>

<!------ FOOTER (SAME ON ALL PAGES) ------>

<footer>
    Here
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i may have some helpful comments.

1. We usually use positive margins. Like `margin-top: 5px` will give you a margin of 5px on the top.
2. nav, h1, div... are block elements. That means that their width is naturally all that is available and a `width: 100%` is usually not necessary.
3. If you do use `width: 100%`, the element will be the width of the parent element. So if you then apply margins, the element will be pushed to one side, but the width o the element will still be 100% of the parent. To avoid this, you can use `width: calc(100% - 2*5px)` for example. But in your case, i don't recommend setting any width at all.

So... less is more. The development tools in firefox or chrome can be a great help to understand what is going on if your css isn't exactly doing what you expected.

Comment: This was super helpful, thank you so much! I have trouble with less is more sometimes, lol. I removed the width from my nav and it worked beautifully! I had to keep width 100% on my image though, otherwise it just was too huge for the webpage. I did find that setting my padding to 0 in the body worked though! No more weird gap. Your comment about parents helped a ton, I can't thank you enough!! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image]

You have to set the padding: 0; in body tag.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to respond! I tried this and it didn't work :/

Comment: Can you send me the whole project? So I can try to test on my local again. Thanks